# When is `\[` preferred over equation* environment?

Tags: equations, environments

When is it preferable to use `\[` instead of `equation*`? I find I often use the `equation*` environment in the following way:

```
\begin{equation*}
some expression
\end{equation*}
```

Should I instead be using the `\[` as below?

```
\[
some expression
\]
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The final lines in `amsmath.sty` are

```
2665 \DeclareRobustCommand{\[}{\begin{equation*}}
2666 \DeclareRobustCommand{\]}{\end{equation*}}
2667 \endinput
2668 %%
2669 %% End of file `amsmath.sty'.
```

This means that, when you load `amsmath`, `\[...\]` is completely equivalent to `\begin{equation*}...\end{equation*}`.

The latter is better if you use numbered equations, because it's easier to switch from unnumbered to numbered or conversely by removing or adding `*`.